# Why is this C program returning correct value in VC++2008?

Tags: c, visual-c++

We know that automatic variables are destroyed upon the return of the function.

Then, why is this C program returning correct value?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>

int * ReturningPointer()
{
    int myInteger = 99;

    int * ptrToMyInteger = &myInteger;

    return ptrToMyInteger;
}

main()
{
    int * pointerToInteger = ReturningPointer();

    printf("*pointerToInteger = %d\n", *pointerToInteger);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Output

```
*pointerToInteger = 99
```

## Edit

Then why is this giving garbage values?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>

char * ReturningPointer()
{
    char array[13] = "Hello World!";

    return array;
}

main()
{
    printf("%s\n", ReturningPointer());

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

### Output

```
x≈§
```

Comment: Asking why is pointless. This would not be reproducible on various OS/compilers/architectures. The C standard doesn't explain what happens: it describes what the result should be, and here, it says that the result is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no answer to that question: your code exhibits undefined behavior. It could print "the right value" as you are seeing, it could print anything else, it could segfault, it could order pizza online with your credit card.

Dereferencing that pointer in `main` is illegal, it doesn't point to valid memory at that point. Don't do it.

There's a big difference between you two examples: in the first case, `*pointer` is evaluated before calling `printf`. So, given that there are no function calls between the line where you get the pointer value, and the `printf`, chances are high that the stack location `pointer` points to will not have been overwritten. So the value that was stored there prior to calling `printf` is likely to be output (that *value* will be passed on to `printf`'s stack, not the pointer).

In the second case, you're passing a pointer to the stack to `printf`. The call to `printf` overwrites (a part of) that same stack region the pointer is pointing to, and `printf` ends up trying to print its own stack (more or less) which doesn't have a high chance of containing something readable.

Note that *you can't rely on getting gibberish either*. Your implementation is free to use a different stack for the `printf` call if it feels like it, as long as it follows the requirements laid out by the standard.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I am not using this code. I am testing the code.

Comment: Yes it does. You can't rely on that program printing that value. It works in this trivial example because nothing overwrote that part of stack you're printing out, but that's besides the point.

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behavior, and it could have launched a missile instead. But it just happened to give you the correct answer.

Think about it, it kind of make sense -- what else did you expect? Should it have given you zero? If so, then the compiler must insert special instructions at the scope end to *erase* the variable's content -- waste of resources. The most natural thing for the compiler to do is to leave the contents unchanged -- so you just got the correct output from undefined behavior by chance.

You could say this behavior is implementation defined. For example. Another compiler (or the same compiler in "Release" mode) may decide to allocate `myInteger` purely in register (not sure if it actually can do this when you take an address of it, but for the sake of argument...), in that case no memory would be allocated for `99` and you would get garbage output.

As a more illustrative (but totally untested) example -- if you insert some `malloc` and exercise some memory usage before `printf` you may find the garbage value you were looking for :P

#### Answer to "Edited" part

The "real" answer that you want needs to be answered in disassembly. A good place to start is `gcc -S` and `gcc -O3 -S`. I will leave the in-depth analysis for wizards that will come around. But I did a cursory peek using GCC and it turns out that `printf("%s\n")` gets translated to `puts`, so the calling convention is different. Since local variables are allocated on the stack, calling a function could "destroy" previously allocated local variables.

Comment: @Saqib well then the compiler had to go out of its way to fill it with "garbage" value from somewhere else. Since the standard does not define what happens in your case (thus "undefined behavior" or implementation defined behavior), your compiler decided not to touch it and left it alone (a reasonable choice).

Comment: Why you expected garbage value? Value is created on stack and during return from function in most cases only stack pointer is moved, value isn't overwritten because it is wast of time. So if you use your pointer just after leaving function it will contain local value. But for example if you call another function or create some new local variables then this stack value will be overwritten. So newer ever try to return anything relaying on this mechanism. If you want check how the stack works on x86 use debugger with assembler and check EBP and ESP registries.

Comment: This is why I think "destroy" is the wrong word, Saquib. The memory remains untouched, it is just available for reuse.

Answer (score 1):

1. Destroying is the wrong word imho. Locals reside on the stack, if the function returns the stack space may be reused again. Until then it is not overwritten and still accessible by pointers which you might not really want (because this might never point to something valid)
2. Pointers are used to address space in memory, for local pointers the same as I described in 1 is valid. However the pointer seems to be passed to the main program.
3. If it really is the address storing the former integer it will result in "99" up until that point in the execution of your program when the program overwrite this memory location. It may also be another 99 by coincidence. Any way: do not do this.

These kind of errors will lead to trouble some day, may be on other machines, other OS, other compiler or compiler options - imagine you upgrade your compiler which may change the behaviour the memory usage or even a build with optimization flags, e.g. release builds vs default debug builds, you name it.

Answer (score 0):

In most C/C++ programs their local variables live on the stack, and `destroyed` means `overwritten` with something else. In this case that particular location had not been overwritten yet when it was passed as a parameter to `printf()`.

Of course, having such code is asking for trouble because per the C and C++ standards it exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

That is `undefined behavior`. That means that anything can happen, even what you would expect.

The tricky part of UB is when it gives you the result you expect, and so you think that you are doing it right. Then, any change in an unrelated part of the program changes that...

Answering your question more specifically, you are returning a pointer to an automatic variable, that no longer exists when the function returns, but since you call no other functions in the middle, it happens to keep the old value.

If you call, for example `printf` twice, the second time it will most likely print a different value.

Answer (score 0):

The key idea is that a variable represents a name and type for value stored somewhere in memory. When it is "destroyed", it means that a) that value can no longer be accessed using that name, and b) the memory location is free to be overwritten.

The behavior is undefined because the implementation of the compiler is free to choose what time after "destruction" the location is actually overwritten.